# best way to manage (add/remove) query-parameters in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I wanted to know what would be the best way to manage `query-paramaters` in `react-router`. Currently I concat the `query` in `url` and push it to `history`, or to remove a query I parse the query again and generate a new string to be cocatenated to the `path`. I was wondering there might be a more native way to do this in `react-router`.